# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'

Tags: python, visual-studio, anaconda, pytorch

Установил Anaconda, добавил интерпретатор в Visual Studio Code, установил pytorch на conda, но тем не менее он не видит этот модуль[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Скорее всего запускаете другим интерпретатором, не из Anaconda.

Comment: в Bar слева снизу можно увидеть, что это conda

Comment: Это ни о чем не говорит еще. Если вы напрямую в терминале запускаете, он берет python из PATH, и не факт что это conda. Выбранный в статус баре интерпретатор влияет на запуск через зеленый треугольник через дополнение Python от Microsoft. Если какой-нибудь code runner установлен, то он ставит свою серую стрелочку поверх зеленой, и игнорирует то что в статус баре выбрано.

Comment: Понял, но в Path я сам поставил anaconda

Comment: Для ответа нужно полное содержимое переменных PATH (пользовательской и системной) и информация о том, как запускаете.